# Не работает скрипт JS, в чём проблема?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Почему-то не работает простенький скрипт на JS. В чём проблема?

```js
function navScript(id) {
  let nav = document.querySelector('id');
  nav.classList.toggle("header-nav-active");
}

headerA1.onclick = navScript(#headerA1);
```

```css
.header-nav a:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.header-nav a {
  color: #a4aead;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 2px solid rgba(91, 97, 104, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.header-nav a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid rgba(91, 97, 104, 1);
}

.header-nav-active {
  border: 2px solid #23b7a4;
  color: #23b7a4;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-nav">
  <div class="header-nav-elements">
    <a id="headerA1" href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
    <a href="#">Team</a>
    <a href="#">Service</a>
    <a href="#">Features</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы есть знак "галочка". Пользуйтесь.

Answer (score 5):

В коде несколько ошибок

1. Чтобы использовать параметр функции его **не нужно** обрамлять в кавычки:

   ```
   let nav = document.querySelector(id);
   ```
2. Чтобы передать строку в качестве параметра ее **нужно** обрамлять в кавычки:

   ```
   navScript('#headerA1')
   ```
3. Чтобы назначить функцию в качестве обработчика, присваивать нужно функцию, а не результат ее вызова. В данном случае вызов `navScript` можно обернуть в анонимную функцию

   ```
   headerA1.onclick = function() {
     navScript("#headerA1");
   }
   ```
4. Чтобы применились новые стили их специфичность должна быть как минимум такой же или выше, чем уже примененные:

   ```
   a.header-nav-active {
   ```

Итого:

```js
function navScript(id) {
  let nav = document.querySelector(id);
  nav.classList.toggle("header-nav-active");
}

headerA1.onclick = function() {
  navScript('#headerA1');
};
```

```css
.header-nav a:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.header-nav a {
  color: #a4aead;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 2px solid rgba(91, 97, 104, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.header-nav a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid rgba(91, 97, 104, 1);
}

a.header-nav-active {
  border: 2px solid #23b7a4;
  color: #23b7a4;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-nav">
  <div class="header-nav-elements">
    <a id="headerA1" href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
    <a href="#">Team</a>
    <a href="#">Service</a>
    <a href="#">Features</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function navScript(selector) {
  let nav = document.querySelector(selector);
  nav.classList.toggle("header-nav-active");
}

headerA1.onclick = function() {
  navScript("#headerA1");
}
```

```css
.header-nav a:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.header-nav a {
  color: #a4aead;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 2px solid rgba(91, 97, 104, 0);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.header-nav a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid rgba(91, 97, 104, 1);
}

.header-nav-active {
  border: 2px solid #23b7a4;
  color: #23b7a4;
  background:lightgreen;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-nav">
  <div class="header-nav-elements">
    <a id="headerA1" href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
    <a href="#">Team</a>
    <a href="#">Service</a>
    <a href="#">Features</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Синтаксис! все проблемы в нём(ковычки, пробелы, табуляции, запятые)

Comment: Отличный oтвет. Молодец!